# Updating the timer value without refreshing the page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having difficulties resolving this problem. The thing is, I have 2 timers on the page, countdown timer #1 (10 mins) and cd timer #2 (25 mins). As soon as the either timer hits "1", I want to e redirected to the another page. It works fine when i refresh page manually, but the problem occurs when I'm already on the page that holds the timers (since the script is loaded before it hits "1"). How do I make it work dynamically? Whenever I'm on page, without refreshing it, I want to be redirected when the timers hit "1". Here's what I've got:

```
var a = $('table.thinline:eq(1)>tbody>tr:eq(2)>td:last').text(); // timer #1
var b = $('table.thinline:eq(1)>tbody>tr:eq(1)>td:last').text(); // timer #2

  if ($('#someId:contains(a)').length && a == "1"){
  window.location.href = "some link";
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not change the countdown functionality, rather than examining the existing text?

Comment: This seems odd. How would text values in table calls be getting updated if you're not reloading the page? Ajax or ? However that table cell content happens dynamically is what should be checking and reloading, rather than testing the content. If that won't work, please elaborate on what you're doing more.

Comment: I'm confused by having 2 JS timers, one at 10 mins and one at 25 mins, and if either hits 1, redirect to another page. What's the point in the 25 minute timer if the user is being redirected after the 10 minute timer hits 1?

Comment: I'm trying to make some Tampermonkey script for a some website. Since I'm newbie and learning about coding, I couldn't realize how to implement countdown functionality. Is there any simple fiddle that can help me? 
It has 2 timers, but once the first timer ends, it'll trigger the window.location.href, and the moment the other function is executed on the new page that im redirected from either #1 timer or #2, i'll be set on the hompage and it goes into loop. So, Homepage - #1 page (according to 1st timer) - Homepage - #2 page (according to 2nd timer) - Homepage etc.

Comment: Basic info on `setTimeout` and `setInterval` as timers: http://jsfiddle.net/oj2m6w5k/
Keep in mind, the second parameter is in milliseconds (so 5000 = 5 seconds).